# How to show and hide some html element with # in the URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to create an website that include some hidden div's , what I want to do that if the URL have #SOMETHING (http://website.com/#SOMETHING) to show on of the dives that have the id SOMETHING (`<div id="SOMETHING">...</div>`) in JavaScript, is it possible?
(what I want to do is that if the URL has #example some script that will remove the hiddenfile class from the div that has the id name of the # (example) )

The code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.hiddenfile {
   opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
   display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="SOMETHING" class="SOMETHING hiddenfile" name="SOMETHING">...</div>
<div id="SOMETHING2" class="SOMETHING2 hiddenfile" name="SOMETHING2">...</div>
<div id="SOMETHING3" class="SOMETHING3 hiddenfile" name="SOMETHING3">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?   Change the visibility of the div when the URL of the page you are currently on is to a target on the page (i.e. Contains `"#SOMETHING") or change the visibility of someone clicks on such a link?

Comment: Change the visibility of the div when the URL of the page you are currently on is to a target on the page (i.e. Contains `"#SOMETHING")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BhojendraRauniyar's answer works, but it only goes so far - will only handle the case for links that land on your page from another page.

If you want the same behavior when clicking on anchor links within the page you will need to implement an `onhashchange` handler and deal with hiding shown elements.

Note that the class names of all your special elements have been changed.

```js
function checkSomething(event) {
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".SOMETHING")].forEach( (div) =>
        // hide or show all "SOMETHING" elements as necessary
        div.classList[(div.id == window.location.hash.substring(1)) ? "remove" : "add"]("hiddenfile")
    )
}

function init() {
    window.onhashchange = checkSomething;
    // need to check if an external link was to an anchor
    checkSomething(); 
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init)
```

```css
.hiddenfile {
   opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
<a href="#SOMETHING">Test for 1st div</a>
<a href="#SOMETHING2">Test for 2nd div</a>
<a href="#SOMETHING3">Test for 3rd div</a></div>
<div id="SOMETHING" class="SOMETHING hiddenfile" name="SOMETHING">SOMETHING</div>
<div id="SOMETHING2" class="SOMETHING hiddenfile" name="SOMETHING2">SOMETHING2</div>
<div id="SOMETHING3" class="SOMETHING hiddenfile" name="SOMETHING3">SOMETHING3</div>
</body>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.hash`:

```
selector = document.querySelector(window.location.hash)
selector.style.display = 'block'
selector.style.opacity = 1
selector.style.visibility = 'visible'
```

Comment: Hi adel. Not to be whiney, but one questionmark is enough :) Also, using a more detailed comment might help to improve an answer, as currently "Why?" can be answered with "Like in this answer.", which doesn't help either of you :) Just saying this as you're new on this site :)